# profit share in a business

Tags: arithmetic

A, B and C invested in the ratio 4:5:7.  C is a sleeping partner so his share of profits will be half of what it would have been if he were a working partner. If they make a profit of Rs. 36,000 of which 25% is reinvested in the business. How much does B gets?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Normally the profit of $C$ would have $$P_c=36000\cdot\frac{75}{100}\cdot\dfrac7{4+5+7}$$

So with change of contract, $C$ will sacrifice  $\dfrac{P_c}2$

Its not clear from the question, in what ratio  $\dfrac{P_c}2$ will be divided between $A,B?$

Will be it be $1:1$ or in their ratio of investment $4:5$